# Stata: find duplicates across variables without considering missing values

Tags: duplicates, stata

Suppose I have a data set with 2 observations and 7 variables (where . indicates missing values):

```
   crop1   crop2   crop3   crop4   nw1   nw2   nw3
   3       7       2       .       3     7     .
   5       9       .       .       5     .     .
```

Now I would like to find the number of duplicated values between Group1 (crop1-crop4) variables and Group2 (nw1-nw3) variables excluding the missing values through generating a new variable called *duplicates*. then the new data set would be the following:

```
   crop1   crop2   crop3   crop4   nw1   nw2   nw3   duplicates
   3       7       2       .       3     7     .     2
   5       9       .       .       5     .     .     1
```

since 2 values (3, 7) are found duplicated for the first observation, and 1 value (5) is found duplicated for the second observation.

What kind of commands I could use to get the new data set?

Comment: What code did you try?

Comment: Maybe something like: make a row-number column, `gen id = _n`; `reshape long crop nw, i(id) j(group)`; and then `duplicates tag id group, gen(d)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand your rules for comparing variables when in the example you have 4 `crop` variables and 3 `nw` variables.

Here is a start on your problem. If your rules differ, please explain them precisely.

I ignore `crop4` and count as a duplicate every comparison where variables **with names with the same numeric suffix** are identical, except that they may not be missing.

```
clear 
input crop1   crop2   crop3   crop4   nw1   nw2   nw3
   3       7       2       .       3     7     .
   5       9       .       .       5     .     .
end 

gen duplicates = 0 

forval j = 1/3 { 
   replace duplicates = duplicates + ((crop`j' == nw`j') & !missing(crop`j', nw`j')) 
} 

list 

     +------------------------------------------------------------+
     | crop1   crop2   crop3   crop4   nw1   nw2   nw3   duplic~s |
     |------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |     3       7       2       .     3     7     .          2 |
  2. |     5       9       .       .     5     .     .          1 |
     +------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks so much! @Nick Cox! That's exactly what I am looking for.